# iterate a column and calculate the variable pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pivot table:

```
Type Time result
y   3
y   4
r   12
r   14
r   11
y   17
y   21
r   5
y   21
r   7
r   4
```

I want to calculate the result according to following two logic:

```
def yellow(time):
    if time < 10:
        return "A"
    elif time  <20:
        return "B"
    else:
        return "C"


   def red(time):
    if time < 10:
        return "A"
    elif time <15:
        return "B"
    else:
        return "C"
```

Finally, I want to calculate the result column by judging: if `type` == y, use yellow evaluation. if `type` == r, use red evaluation.

Any one has good solution by use pandas?

Comment: IIUC then `df.loc[df['Type'] == 'y', 'Result'] = df['Time'].apply(yellow)` and similarly for the other `df.loc[df['Type'] == 'r', 'Result'] = df['Time'].apply(red)`

Comment: @EdChum you save me days! appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 masks to filter the df so you can selectively `apply` your functions:

```
In [224]:
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'y', 'result'] = df['Time'].apply(yellow)
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'r', 'result'] = df['Time'].apply(red)
df

Out[224]:
   Type  Time result
0     y     3      A
1     y     4      A
2     r    12      B
3     r    14      B
4     r    11      B
5     y    17      B
6     y    21      C
7     r     5      A
8     y    21      C
9     r     7      A
10    r     4      A
```

Here by using `loc` we perform row label selection, the mask from `df['Type'] == 'y']` will return a boolean mask which we use to select only the rows that meet that criteria:

```
In [227]:
df['Type'] == 'y'

Out[227]:
0      True
1      True
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6      True
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
Name: Type, dtype: bool

In [228]:
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'y']

Out[228]:
  Type  Time  result
0    y     3     NaN
1    y     4     NaN
5    y    17     NaN
6    y    21     NaN
8    y    21     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. Btw, how bout if my pivot table has some empty rows like:
`y   3
y   4
r   12
r   14
r   11
y   17
y   21
r   5
y   21

r   7
r   4` can I add one judgement to only calculate the row that is not empty?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by empty rows, the boolean mask should still select those rows and then assign new values

Comment: can we discuss in chat?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to leave work, you could post another question explaining your problem and I will have a look later if I get time, as usual post raw data and code to reproduce your df and the desired output to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with adding exact colour to the desired output.

```
result = ""

def yellow(time):
    if time < 10:
        return "A"
    elif time  <20:
        return "B"
    else:
        return "C"

def red(time):
    if time < 10:
        return "A"
    elif time <15:
        return "B"
    else:
        return "C"

def generic(type_of,time):
    if type_of == 'y':
        result = yellow(int(time))
        print("{}\t{}".format(type_of,time))
        print("\033[91m Result = {}\033[00m" .format(result))
    else:
        result = red(int(time))
        print("{}\t{}".format(type_of,time))
        print("\033[93m Result =  {}\033[00m".format(result))

flag = 0

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in lines:
        if( flag == 0):
            flag = 1
            continue
        splitting = i.split("\t")
        generic(splitting[0],splitting[1])
        result = " "
```

Output as follows:

[image: Output result in colour]

Comment: how is this answer related to what to what the OP has asked for?